# SQL OR comparison just one result

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

Im trying to make an SQL query that depends on the result only return one column, I have the next table:

```
 day1       | day2       | day3
 -------------------------------------
 2013-02-25 | 2013-02-26 | 2013-02-27
```

---

So I want the next query return only one day row,

```
 SELECT * FROM days WHERE day1 = '2013-02-25' or day2 = '2013-02-25' or day = '2013-02-25'
```

I want the next, only the row who has the value.

```
day        |
------------
2013-02-25 |
```

Comment: Does the table have other columns besides these 3?

Comment: this *looks* like a poorly designed  table

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT day1 AS TheDay FROM days WHERE day1 = '2013-02-25' 
UNION 
SELECT day2           FROM days WHERE day2 = '2013-02-25' 
UNION
SELECT day3           FROM days WHERE day3 = '2013-02-25'
```